# create-react-app failed to compile, but process won't exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, create-react-app

I have an application made with `create-react-app` and I have a strange issue where the script will not exit when there is an error, essentially:

```
~/my-project$ ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/library/index.ts
Cannot find file './ApiClient.generated' in './src/library'.


I can continue typing into my terminal
```

When the file is present, I can build and compile the project correctly.

```
~/my-project$ node -v
v14.5.0
~/my-project$ npm -v
6.14.5
~/my-project$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It figures I'd find the answer just after I post [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7386#issuecomment-523111741) indicates that it is an issue with `node-sass`. Replacing it with `sass` resolves the issue.